# Refactor Linq code and "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method"

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I am trying to refactor Linq to Entity query to prevent writing duplicate code but I can't avoid a "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method" exception. The reason is `IsUserActive` method.

I am providing the code below as example

```
public static bool IsUserActive(this User user)
{
 return user.Orders.Any(c => c.Active && (c.TransactionType == TransactionType.Order || c.TransactionType == TransactionType.Subscription));
}

public IQueryable<UserView> GetView()
{
 return context.users.Select(p => new UserView
            {
                Id = p.Id,
                Active =p.IsUserActive()

            });
}
```

Is it possible to refactor Linq code to prevent duplication in my situation?

- I can't use IList instead of IQueryable.
- I know why this exception happens, no need to explain.

Comment: Just inline the method.

Comment: The IsUserActive is used in many queries and I would like to have it as method. This this just example, there are many cases when Linq code is duplicated in many queries and I do not find a way to refactor queries. I get the exception because Linq to Entity tries to translate every method in query to sql.

Comment: Have you tried a regular method rather than an extension method? Linq might just be getting confused

Comment: I think there is a miss understanding the concept here IsUserActive is not a linq or dynmaic linq extension So You need to call an extention method from Linq is this correct?

Comment: Do not make difference regular or extension method.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use your method in a lot of places, I don't think you can do anything except store it as an *expression* and then referring to that expression wherever you were calling the original method:

```
public static Expression<Func<User, bool>> IsUserActive = user =>
    user.Orders.Any(c => c.Active &&
                         (c.TransactionType == TransactionType.Order ||
                          c.TransactionType == TransactionType.Subscription));

public IQueryable<UserView> GetView()
{
    return context.users.Select(p => new UserView
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            Active = IsUserActive(p)
        });
}
```

EDIT: OK, so this doesn't work. You can't just "call" an expression like this. The only alternative I can think of is to turn your whole `Select` parameter into an expression:

```
public static Expression<Func<User, UserView>> UserToUserView = user =>
    new UserView
        {
            Id = user.Id,
            Active =  user.Orders.Any(c => c.Active &&
                         (c.TransactionType == TransactionType.Order ||
                          c.TransactionType == TransactionType.Subscription)
        };

public IQueryable<UserView> GetView()
{
    return context.users.Select(UserToUserView);
}
```

Comment: And the reason is that LINQ can't map a method in code to SQL statements, but it can map an expression

Comment: I get compilation error. The name 'IsUserActive' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Tomas If the new `Expression` is in the same static class where your extension methods were, you'll need to prefix references to it with the name of said static class.

Comment: The class, method and expression are static methods and I get compilation error on IsUserActive. When I move mouse on the expression method VS show error "Method, Delegate or Event is expected". Something wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is little tricky, but this is how we are doing it. You can combine multiple IQueryables into one as shown below.

```
public static IQueryable<Order> ActiveOrdersQuery(this MyDBEntities db)
{
    return db.orders.Where(
           o=> o.Active && 
               (o.TransactionType == TransactionType.Order ||
                o.TransactionType == TransactionType.Subscription )));

}

public IQueryable<UserView> GetView()
{
    var q = context.ActiveOrdersQuery();
    return context.users.Select( x=> new UserView{
         Id = x.Id,
         Active = q.Any( o=> o.UserId == x.Id)
    });
}
```

The only problem is you have to explicitly compare foreign keys. But this results in exactly same SQL and will perform same.

This way you can refactor common queries and use them inside your views.